# How to setup a simple serverless framework monorepo

Tags: webpack, serverless-framework, monorepo

I want to store all my services in a single repository in order to unify packaging and deployment process.
Briefly, I want to hoist almost all dev dependencies to the root level of my repo:

- Serverless Framework and plugins
- Typescript and Webpack
- Linter, prettier, husky
- aws-sdk and other shared dependencies

All the service specific dependencies should be stored at the service level.
Target directory structure should look like this:

```
node_modules/
shared/
services/
--service-a/
----node_modules
----src/
----serverless.yml
--service-b/
----node_modules
----src/
----serverless.yml
.eslintrc.js
.prettierrc
package.json
package-lock.json
serverless-compose.yml
tsconfig.json
webpack.config.js
```

How can I setup following project? How to setup webpack to work together with serverless-compose and dependencies separation? I don't want to use solutions like Lerna/NX/Turborepo to keep it as simple as possible.

Maybe I'm wrong, please point me a proper direction

Comment: Have you had a look at pnpm [workspace](https://pnpm.io/workspaces) and `workspace:` protocol? This might be helpful to create a workspace (monorepo) structure without the need for external tools. For example, you can take a look at this demo [Vue 3 and pnpm workspace boilerplate](https://github.com/ghiscoding/vue3-pnpm-workspace) I made. Note that I don't know anything about serverless, so I'm not sure if it's helpful or not, but probably still good to know info

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling with the configuration of a monorepo with serverless framework.

Consider that Turborepo is only leveraging npm / yarn / pnpm and it's more an orchestrator of tasks than a fully monorepo manager.

I'm going in the pnpm workspace way, and I'm only stuck with the correct dependency bundling of the serverless stack deployed by serverless framework.

For the remaining packages, here what I've done:

1. Set up pnpm workspaces by declaring all the packages paths in pnpm-workspace.yaml file in the root of the project.
2. Add a root .gitignore (where you ignore .turbo folders) and a main package.json file
3. remove all the node_modules folders in each package folder
4. add a package.json file for each module/package you are creating, being aware of the "name" key in each file.
5. if one package (package A) depends on another one (package B), you can add the dependency in the "dependencies" or "devDependencies" on package A package.json, addressing it with the key/value "packageBName" : "workspace:*"
6. once you have the packages "internal" dependencies settled down, run a pnpm install in the root folder.

Here you have the dependency resolution setup and then you can use the official guides to setup a common linting package, a common tsconfig package to share configuration between all the monorepo packages.

PNPM package resolution docs: https://pnpm.io/how-peers-are-resolved

Here is an example of how it will resolve dependencies.

```
├── node_modules/
│   ├── ~~ dependencies defined in the root package.json
├── packages/
│   ├── package-A/
│   |   └── node_modules/ ~~ dependencies defined in package-A/package.json
|   |       └── @yourScope/package-B
|   |   └── package.json
|   └── package-B/ 
│   |   └── node_modules/ ~~ dependencies defined in package-B/package.json
|   |   └── package.json
├── package.json
├── pnpm-lock.yaml
└── pnpm-workspace.yaml
```

In my project I have the correct scripts running (lint, build, test and deploy) but I noticed that not all the dependencies of the serverless stack I push to AWS are bundled correctly.

I'll keep trying to figure it out and I'll reach you if I have some news.

Hope this little hint can help you solve your problem.

Good luck!